# using same statement object to execute multiple queries in multiple threads?

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading, jdbc

Is it a good idea to re-use java.sql.Statement object to execute multiple queries **in multiple threads simultaneously**?

I've read somewhere that it's recommended to reuse same statement object, however it was sequential execution.

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
```

Now if I use this single statement instance to run `executeUpdate()` for multiple queries in **multiple threads simultaneously**?

Note that it's not PreparedStatement and I am not getting any ResultSet.

I think answer depends on two scenarios:

1. If queries are mutually exclusive, then it should be okay.
2. If queries are working on same set of data, then there may be issues.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's definitely not a good idea. For one, `ResultSets` are associated with a `Statement`. You don't want to be iterating through a `ResultSet` when another thread suddenly makes a new query (the `ResultSet` would be closed, at least if the driver is a well behaved one).

There is also nowhere an indication that `Statements` would be thread-safe. If it's not clearly indicated, it's not thread-safe (at least in most cases).

Comment: Thanks. What if it's not a PreparedStatement and there is no ResultSet? It's just update, delete, insert queries and those are mutually exclusive queries?

Comment: @Kayaman: As you said yourself, there is no thread-safety guarantee, so it’s no matter of the driver being “well behaved” when it comes to closing an old `ResultSet` in a *concurrent* scenario. There is not even a definition of “old” then. Besides all other possible behavior a thread might receive the `ResultSet` of the other thread’s query.

Comment: @ankur: Simply *don’t do it*. There is not even a guaranty that a JDBC driver supports multi-threading when using multiple `Statement`s. You have to study the specific driver’s documentation to learn about it’s multi-threading capabilities.